# irritating window locations after a closed clam

Tags: closed-clamshell

I switch back and forth, frequently, between 'closed clam' with a large monitor and 'just the laptop monitor' with a Retina MBP.

Whenever I switch, all my windows appear in unhelpful locations sticking off the edges of the visible screen. This happens in both directions.

I currently run Yosemite.

Is there a way to make them recenter?

Answer (score 1):

I use an AppleScript tied to a keyboard shortcut that runs as an Automator service.
Something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "iTunes" -- non running procs fail silently
    try
        set position of front window to {22, 26} -- or you can call windows by name
    end try
end tell
end tell
```

You'll need two scripts, one for each configuration. Obviously, you'll have to enter all your windows and Apps into the code, so this is only a worthwhile effort for the stuff you commonly use.

Comment: Two scripts might be easier/quicker to code however if I needed a script two work in two different hardware configurations I'd code a single script to work under both configurations.  Write once use many! :)

Comment: @user3439894 :    **do shell script " defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver | grep -w -m 2 Unit"** Then count the how many times "Unit" shows up in the result string, and use that to branch.

Comment: The bounds `{22, 14}` sets the top of the window under the menu bar. To justify it to the top left of the Desktop, it would be better set to `{0, 22}`.

Comment: Fixed. {22, 26} will do. Point is you can put it wherever you want. The example also makes for a nice way to recover windows that have somehow gotten entirely off screen, or to hide windows entirely off screen.